# Split strings in an array by last comma within each string

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, split, hive

Say, I have an array of strings in hive, e.g.:

```
hive> select array from my_table;
["\"string1\"","\"string2_component_a\",\"string2_component_b\"","\"string3_component_a\",\"string3_component_b\",\"string3_component_c\""]
```

As you can see there are following three strings:

```
"string1"
"string2_component_a","string2_component_b"
"string3_component_a","string3_component_b","string3_component_c"
```

What I want is to split every element by the **last** comma within each string. So, the resulting array should have the following 5 components:

```
"string1"
"string2_component_a"
"string2_component_b"
"string3_component_a","string3_component_b"
"string3_component_c"
```

Is there a way to achieve this in hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oneliner using

- [`String.split(String reges,int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))
- [`ApacheCommons`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) `StringUtils.countMatches`

```
yourString.split(",", StringUtils.countMatches(yourString, ".") - 1);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Are you sure I can use it i hive?

According Hive [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted):

> Requirements
>   Java 1.7
>   Note:  Hive versions 1.2 onward require Java 1.7 or newer. Hive versions 0.14 to 1.1 work with Java 1.6 as well. Users are strongly advised to start moving to Java 1.8 (see HIVE-8607).

So yes, you will be able to use `String.split` and `StringUtils` from `Apache Commons` without any prblem.

Comment: Are you sure I can use it i hive?

Comment: I am not quite sure I can use it directly in hive. But maybe this can be used to create a UDF... I am pretty new to java-world :-)

Comment: @DatamineR looking hive documentation, yes, you can use my solution.

Answer (score 0):

be also aware of google guava library. In fact, the Splitter is so powerful
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter